# Making VScode look like the Vscode in every tutorial

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

after installing VScode I noticed that my editor looks different than every single other editor in every tutorial and I'm not sure why? I'd like to make mine look similar in layout if possible.

This is what I have, you'll notice there is no bar to the left side of the screen

[image: This is what I have, you'll notice there is no bar to the left side of the screen]

This is what I want, there is a bar with icons on the left side of the screen

[image: This is what I want, there is a bar with icons on the left side of the screen]

I have tried googling to no avail , I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail. Would appreciate any leads, thanks for reading.

Comment: VS and VSC will never look the same and will never have the same workflow.

Answer (score 0):

What You have in your first image is a software called `Visual Studio`.`Visual Studio` and `Visual Studio Code` don't have much in common except the name, which is due to the fact that they both come from Microsoft.

Although you can actually download `Visual Studio Code` from the [Visual Studio website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/), there is also a separate [website for `VScode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/).